# Nodejs image resizing with imagemagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick-convert

I want am trying to write an image resizing script using `nodejs`and `imagemagick` that sets the `src` path from the url and then defines the `dst` path based on the image name retrieved from the url. However I get the following error when I run my program and the image is not resized.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Error :

```
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `favicon.ico': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
convert: no images defined `'images/dst/favicon500.ico'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `favicon.ico': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
convert: no images defined `'images/dst/favicon800.ico'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `favicon.ico': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
convert: no images defined `'images/dst/favicon200.ico'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `favicon.ico': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
convert: no images defined `'images/dst/favicon45.ico'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `'images/dst/ferrari45845.jpg'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `'images/dst/ferrari458200.jpg'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `'images/dst/ferrari458500.jpg'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `'images/dst/ferrari458800.jpg'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

This is my server code:

```
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    im = require("imagemagick");



// create server

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    // get the full pathname
    var _originalPathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    // we only need the pathname without the first "/"
    var _pathname = _originalPathname.substring(1);

    // get the file name and file extension
    var _img = _pathname.split("/").pop();

    // get file name
    var _imgName = _img.split(".").shift();

    // get file extension
    var _fileExtension = _img.split(".").pop();

    var _800px = {
        width: 800,
        srcPath: _pathname,
        dstPath: "'images/dst/" + _imgName + 800 + "." + _fileExtension + "'"
    };

    var _500px = {
        width: 500,
        srcPath: _pathname,
        dstPath: "'images/dst/" + _imgName + 500 + "." + _fileExtension + "'"
    };

    var _200px = {
        width: 200,
        srcPath: _pathname,
        dstPath: "'images/dst/" + _imgName + 200 + "." + _fileExtension + "'"
    };

    var _45px = {
        width: 45,
        srcPath: _pathname,
        dstPath: "'images/dst/" + _imgName + 45 + "." + _fileExtension + "'"
    };

    var _sizesArray = [_800px, _500px, _200px, _45px];

    var len = _sizesArray.length;


    // apply img resize to our src image looping through our array of sizes
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        im.resize(_sizesArray[i], function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    };

    res.end("Image resize complete!");
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: No sure, but it seems that it cannot find the path to the original image, what is the value of `_pathname` which you use as `srcPath`?

Comment: @IvanFraixedes, yeap. I got it working. Had two extra and unnecessary `'` when defining the `dstPath`

Comment: @IvanFraixedes any idea why it would get the `favicon` though?

Comment: Yes, because browsers make automatically that request